# Is there any Hausdorff, $\sigma$-compact and nowhere locally compact space with every non dense open set not $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I was studying some counterexamples, and found out that, if a space $X$ is Hausdorff and nowhere locally compact, then every continuous function $f : X^* \to \mathbb{R}$ is constant, where $X^* $ is the one-point compactification of $X$. Further, if $V$ is an open set of $X$ which is not dense, this means $\operatorname{cl}_{X^* } (V) = \operatorname{cl}_X (V) \cup \{ \infty \}$ is a proper subset of $X^*$. If $V$ is $\sigma$-compact, this means $V$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X^* $. Therefore, we have an example of an open $F_\sigma$-set whose closure is not the support of a continuous function. This cannot happen for a normal space. I would like to know if the condition $\sigma$-compact for $X$ is sufficient to find such a $V$. Examples of such spaces are: the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, the prime integer topology, the $p$-adic topology, and many others. For countable spaces, the result is trivial, since every singleton is compact.

Comment: I don't understand the question: if $X$ $\sigma$-compact, it cannot be the case that **every** open set is not $\sigma$-compact, as $X$ is. So please state an exact question: do you want one such open set (easy) or what else?

Comment: I don't think the statement "$X$ is Hausdorff and not locally compact, then every continuous $f:X^\ast \to \Bbb R$ is constant" is true. This already fails for simple examples, like $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Why does this fails for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Every compact space in $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior, therefore for every $p \in \mathbb{Q}$, and every neighborhoods $N(p)$ and $N(\infty)$, they are not disjoint. Suppose $f(p) = \alpha \neq \beta = f(\infty)$, then there are disjoint neighborhoods $B(\alpha, r_1)$ and $B(\beta, r_2)$ and their preimage are disjoint, which cannot happen.

Comment: You're right about $\Bbb Q$ but $X=[0,1] \cup (\Bbb Q \cap [2,3])$ does work as an example about the statement I quoted. You argument works only on the nowhere locally compact part, not the closed interval. So the assumption on $X$ needs to be more than just Hausdorff and non-locally compact.

Comment: Hm, okay, yes, I'm using nowhere locally compact, my mistake.

Comment: "If $V$ is $\sigma$-compact then $V$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X^\ast$", why, if $X^\ast$ is not always Hausdorff or KC, especially not when $X$ is nowhere locally compact?

Comment: Well, since $V$ is a subset of $X$ and all of closed set of $X^* $ contained in $X$ are the compact sets (we have two "classes" of open sets: the open sets of $X$, whose complement contains $\infty$, and the complement of compact sets). Therefore if $V$ is $\sigma$-compact in the topology of $X$, then $V$ is $F_\sigma$ in the topology of $X^* $

Comment: $K$ compact in $X$ means $K\cup \{\infty\}$ closed in $X^\ast$, so $O=\cup_n K_n = (\cup_n (K_n \cup \{\infty\})) \cap V$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X^\ast$, indeed.